# Create HTML element with YUI

Tags: yui

I am using following code to create a html element in the page body with using YUI.
This code doesn't produce any error.

The issue is, the paragraph element is not created in the html page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YUI Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.14.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Create a YUI sandbox on your page.
            YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
                // Create DOM nodes.
                var contentNode = Y.Node.create('<p>');

                contentNode.setHTML('This is a para created by YUI...');
            });           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page body section...</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node is created, but it is also detached from the DOM. You have to attach it to the DOM by using either

```
Y.one('body').append(contentNode);
```

or

```
contentNode.appendTo(Y.one('body'));
```

or

```
Y.one('nav.main-navigation').insert(contentNode, 'before');
```

or any of the other methods for manipulating dom in YUI.